# Doing math in pandas using .ix

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to divide one cell (later a series of them) using the .ix function in pandas dataframe.

An example of one that works below:

```
fc = pd.read_csv("H://mydata2.csv", "r", delimiter=",", index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
aq = pd.read_csv("H://mydata.csv", "r", delimiter=",", index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

fc.ix[fc.index.weekday == 6, 'c2':'c4'] = fc.ix[fc.index.weekday == 6, 'c2':'c4'] * .7
```

however, when I try to do the math from one cell to another, it returns NaN values

```
fc.ix[fc.index.astype(datetime) == datetime(2015, 12, 25), 'c2'] = fc.ix[fc.index.astype(datetime) == datetime(2015, 12, 25), 'c2'].astype(float) / aq.ix[aq.index.astype(datetime) == datetime(2014, 12, 25), 'c4'].astype(float))
```

The problem seems to stem from doing the operation using two data frames. When I use this method to do math on values within the same dataframe, it causes no problems.

I am using the .ix method because it is the only way I know to select rows/columns using a condition like fc.index.weekday == 6. However, I am sure there is a better way and am open to suggestions if this method isn't the right way. I am trying to avoid using the python loop method to do the math because it will eventually be doing math on a lot of rows and I need the efficiency of the compiled pandas methods.

Sample data is below. The aq data is the same data but from a year before.

```
    Date      c1     c2      c3     c4
12/19/2014  5486    1265    908.6   19
12/20/2014  5513    1334    937.8   20
12/21/2014  5540    1403    967 21
12/22/2014  5567    1472    996.2   22
12/23/2014  5594    1541    1025.4  23
12/24/2014  5621    1610    1054.6  24
12/25/2014  5648    1679    1083.8  25
12/26/2014  5675    1748    1113    26
12/27/2014  5702    1817    1142.2  27
12/28/2014  5729    1886    1171.4  28
12/29/2014  5756    1955    1200.6  29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does arithmetic by matching indices. Since your second dataframe is from the year before, the indices don't match, so the result will be NA everywhere.

Try doing `fc = fc.set_index(fc.index.dayofyear)` (and the same for the other dataframe) before doing your calculation.

---

Edit: if you're just trying to compare single results rather than full columns, using direct indexing rather than masking should be fine. For example, assuming your index consist of dates, simply use `fc.ix['2015-12-25', 'c2'] / aq.ix['2014-12-25', 'c4']`:

```
fc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 4),
                  columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-12-20', periods=6, freq='D'))
aq = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 4),
                  columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2014-12-20', periods=6, freq='D'))
result = fc.ix['2015-12-25', 'c2'] / aq.ix['2014-12-25', 'c4']
print(result)
# 0.943558115233
```

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. how do I do formulas on dayofyear? fc.ix[fc.index.dayofyear == 359?

Or maybe a better question is, how can I use the above to return the value instead of the index, do the math, then store it back to the original index? or would this break the speed of using pandas math?

Either way, thank you!

Comment: The other problem is, I'm not sure I can use the above method because I need to retain the date index for other functions.

Comment: Interesting. That definitely solves this issue, but I'm going to need to post another question about formula selecting indexes. i.e. 
RefDate = datetime.now() - Timedelta(days=1)
                                           fc.ix[fc.index.astype(datetime) >= RefDate - Timedelta(days=90) and fc.index.astype(datetime) <= RefDate , 'QOutbound']

That is within a single dataframe though, so a different question is in order. Thank you for all your help :)